# Is there a Chinese equivalent song of 'auld lang syne'?

Tags: mainland-china

In Western countries (or New Zealand at least), auld lang syne is a very common song over the the New Year holiday. Is there an equivalent song in Chinese that everyone instantly associates with Chinese new year? Or are there a range of popular new year songs?

Comment: What does "auld lang syne" mean?

Comment: It comes from Scottish originally - just a common song for singing around the new years holiday. I suggest you check out the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auld_Lang_Syne) to give you some more information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this famous song has a Chinese version called 《友谊地久天长》(*the friendship will last forever*), however, we traditionally don't sing songs to celebrate over festivals, so this song is not popular in this peroid of time.

I can't think of such a popular song as "auld lang syne" in the west. Over this period, you wll find a lot of songs(different melodies, different lyrics, different singers) with the same theme "happy new year" on the street or in the markets(to convey the happiness or to attract more customers). I would like to recommend Timi Zhuo(卓依婷), a female singer famous for her "new year" type songs.

Comment: Thanks very much - I will check out the music you suggested. Cheers!